# jQuery slideToggle on table lags then toggles (no slide)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a table which will have a header row, a "item" row, if you will, and a details row.  The item row and the details row will be repeating, so that every even numbered row in the table (i.e., the second row in the table is the first "item" row) will be an item row and every odd numbered will be a "details" row, except for the header.

The script below works, except the jQuery slideToggle is not sliding.  On the expand action, it just opens up, and on the collapse action it takes a second and then disappears.

See the table structure and script below: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/we5ue/) (click the "Column[1,2,3] row)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sometable tr:odd").addClass("odd");
    $("#sometable tr:not(.odd)").hide();
    $("#sometable tr:first-child").show();

    $("#sometable tr.odd").click(function () {
        $(this).next("tr").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

```
<table id="sometable">
<tr>
    <th>
        Header1
    </th>
    <th>
        Header2
    </th>
    <th>
        Header3
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Column1
    </td>
    <td>
        Column2
    </td>
    <td>
        Column3
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <p>Details about item 1</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`slideToggle` does not work well with `tr`.  I believe it has to do with `overflow: hidden` not working with `tr`.

The easiest workaround would be to simply `slideToggle` the `p` rather than the `tr`.

http://jsfiddle.net/hEyDN/4/